# jQuery function - if Saturday delivery is selected do this

Tags: jquery, function, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have this fiddle which uses datepicker to display only Saturdays.

What I need to do is come up with a function to check which option is selected for delivery and if Saturday is selected to only display Saturdays on the datepicker.

If the other 2 options are selected then display the calendar as normal.

http://jsfiddle.net/X325G/519/

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() 
== 6,""]}
});
```

Below is the code that displays all calendar days:

```
jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
  minDate: +1, 
  maxDate: '+2M',
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 0), ''];
  } 

});
```

[Screenshot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osXKN.png)

Comment: I guess you want to have different calendar options when you select the saturday delivery? You should create an example with at least 2 radio buttons and apply a change listener on them to display different calendars or change the options. have you tried that? Also be aware the calendar is just an optional way to choose a date, users can still type whatever date they want if you don't restrict that.

Comment: I have been trying to do something similar to this but my attempts have failed. My jquery knowledge isn't too avanced. If you could post an example that would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you have to do achieving this functionality.

1. Trigger the on-click event for radio buttons
2. validate the current value
3. based on the validation, display either normal one or only visible Saturday one.
4. Before updating the date-picker, you have to destroy the current displaying date-picker, so that it will display the updated one after the changes.

**JS**

```
$('input[name="test"]').on('click', function(){
    $("#dp").datepicker("destroy");
    if($(this).val() == "Saturday") {            
        $("#dp").datepicker({
           beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 6,""]}
         });
    } else {
       $("#dp").datepicker();
    }
 });
 $("#dp").datepicker();
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
   <input type="radio" name="test" value="Standard" /> Standard
   <input type="radio" name="test" value="Express" /> Express
   <input type="radio" name="test" value="Saturday" /> Saturday
 </div>
 <input type="text" id="dp"/>
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('input[name="test"]').on('click', function(){
   $("#dp").datepicker("destroy");
   if($(this).val() == "Saturday") {      
      $("#dp").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 6,""]}
    });
  } else {
    $("#dp").datepicker();
  }
});
$("#dp").datepicker();
```

```css
 article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  html { font-size: 90%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="Standard" /> Standard
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="Express" /> Express
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="Saturday" /> Saturday
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="dp"/>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X325G/581/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple solution, it creates a datepicker first and when the value of the radio button is changed to saturday delivery it will restrict the values as in your example. This example uses the datepicker "option" to change the `beforeShowDay` function, so it reuses the actual datepicker.

It should give you some ideas how to solve the problem.

```js
$("#dp").datepicker();

$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
  if (this.value === "saturday")
    $("#dp").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 6,""]});
  else
    $("#dp").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", null);
});
```

```css
 article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  html { font-size: 64.5%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="radio" id="deliveryStandard" name="delivery" value="standard" checked>
<label for="deliveryStandard">Standard</label>

<input type="radio" id ="deliverySaturay" name="delivery" value="saturday">
<label for="deliverySaturay">Saturday</label>
    
<input type="text" id="dp"/>
```